# How can I print a value of a datapicker form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I'm implementing a little project for myself. The project is a booking site.

In particular, when the user visits the site, it compiles a form:

`name
surname
email
object
check-in date
check-out date`

The two fields `check-in` and `check-out` are of type datepicker.

When the user chooses the two dates, I want the site to show the offers that the user can purchase.

My problem are the two dates. How can I pass the dates' value to PHP from JS to do the query and search in my database which offers are available for the user to purchase?

Here my code:

JS code

```js
$(function(){

    var self=this;
     self.check_next=[0,0];
    $('#data_arrivo').datepicker({
        minDate:0,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
                    var depart = jQuery.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', selectedDate);
                    depart.setDate(depart.getDate() + 1);
                   $('#data_partenza').datepicker("option", "minDate", depart);
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('#data_partenza').datepicker('show');
        }, 16);
             self.check_next[0]=1;
        if(check_div(self.check_next))load_date_picker();
                }
            });
    
   $('#data_partenza').datepicker({      
        minDate:0,
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        onSelect:function(selectedDate){
              self.check_next[1]=1;
        if(check_div(self.check_next))load_date_picker();
            
        }
        });
});
function check_div(ar){
    if(ar[0] && ar[1])return true;
    else return false;
}

function load_date_picker(){
    $('.show_div').removeClass('hidden');
    }

function leggi_dati(){
    var data_arrivo = $('#data_arrivo').val();
    var nome=$('#cnome').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/lavoro/wp-content/themes/rolenzo/page-templates/test-page-template.php',
            dataType : "json",
            data:$('#commentForm').serialize(),
            success:function(data){
                console.log("Done");
            }
        });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.4/datepicker.js"></script>
<link rel='stylesheet' type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.4/datepicker.css"/>

<span style="padding-top: 17px; padding-left:7px; display:block; float:left; width:40%; height:10%;">Selezionare Data di arrivo</span>
             <p><input style="display:block; float:left; width:60%; height:10%;" type="text" name="data_arrivo" id="data_arrivo" class="datepicker" required></p>
         </div>
         <div style="float:left; width:100%; height:100%;">
             <p><span style="padding-top: 17px; padding-left:7px; display:block; float:left; width:40%; height:10%;">Selezionare Data di partenza</span></p>
             <p><input style="display:block; float:left; width:60%; height:10%;" type="text" name="data_partenza" id="data_partenza" class="datepicker" required></p>
         </div>
         <div class="hidden show_div">
         <p style= "text-align:center; font-weight:bold;">Offerte Disponibili nel periodo da Lei selezionato : </p>
             <?php
               $date = urldecode ($_GET['data_arrivo']);

                echo "chosen date is: ".$date;
             
             
             ?>
             </div>
```

Comment: You mean something like `$('#data_arrivo').datepicker('getDate')` ? This method will return the value of the date picker.

Comment: and how can i call in php the date. It's ok like $_POST['data_arrivo'];??

Comment: If you used POST to send the data to the server, yes.

Comment: i did it , but the print results is nothing. it Doesn't show nothing

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to use a PHP function createFromFormat on the js date using the correct format, such as:

```
$jsDate = $_POST['data_arrivo']
$dateTime = DateTime::createFromFormat('d/m/Y', $jsDate);
```

You should then be able to use $dateTime to query your db (assuming a PHP date object will be compatible)

BUT keep in mind this will create a date object at the time 0:00:00 on your selected dates, which might or might not be what you want. If you want to include the full day of the to date, you will need to set the time on the to date to 23:59:59 for example.

Comment: if i do print $dataTime , why it doesn't print??

Comment: what is $jsDate equal to?

Comment: i confused my self. I have this situation. I want that when the user select the 2 date, the site shows the offer. So i have 1 form with 2 field 1) Check in 2)check out (in my code check in is data_arrivo and check out is data_partenza) i do the ajax call , its correct like this? function leggi_dati(){
    var data_arrivo = $('#data_arrivo').val();
    var nome=$('#cnome').val();
    $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/lavoro/wp-content/themes/rolenzo/page-templates/test-page-template.php',
            dataType : "json",
            data:$('#commentForm').serialize